# Eloquent - nullable date column returned as 0000-00-00

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've encountered a problem with Eloquent model. My database column is defined as

```
date_to date null
```

It is also defined as `nullable()` in migration.

When I select a database record (either with query builder or directly via `find($id)`), value for `$model->date_to` is always returned by Eloquent as `0000-00-00` (In MySQL, this column is properly set to `NULL`).

Am I missing something? I am not that experienced with Eloquent.

---

Here's my model:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table_name';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'member_id',
        'date_from',
        'date_to',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'date_from',
        'date_to',
    ];

}
```

Table structure:

```sql
create or replace table table_name
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    member_id int not null,
    date_from date null,
    date_to date null,
)
charset=utf8;
```

---

**UPDATE**

As a temporary fix I used:

```php
public function getDateToAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value == '0000-00-00') {
        return null;
    }
    return $value;
}

public function getDateFromAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value == '0000-00-00') {
        return null;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: you may have added the field in `protected $dates` variable of the Model

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya Yes, I have added it to this protected array. But at first, it was not set in `$dates` array, and the result was unfortunately the same.

Comment: Could you share related eloquent model?

Comment: @Sevan I have updated my post with model definition

Comment: @mkrowiarz have you notice the post request data for that date field ?

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya I'm sorry, could you be more specific? I do not really understand the question about post request data

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Currently `illuminate/database` package is at version `8.45.1`.

Comment: @mkrowiarz I mean the post request data means, when you submit the form what type of value you get for the date field ?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $casts = [
    'date_from' => 'date:Y-m-d',
    'date_to' => 'date:Y-m-d',
];
```

Have you ever try to [casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) like above?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes. When I call `$model->date_to` it returns a Carbon instance with invalid date.

Comment: Could you please provide the structure of the table from MySQL?
By the way which version of Laravel you are using?

Comment: of course, updated my post with a table structure